# Memory with readAllBytes and read

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I have a situation with ZIP-archives and idk what's better method for unpacking.

I correctly understand that if we will use **InputStream.readAllBytes()** and next **OutputStream.write(ourAllBytes)** - that bad practice (if arhive have file < 2gb, for example), and i need use fixed count of bytes for reading and writing (**InputStream.read(buffer)** and **OutputStream.write(buffer, 0 len)**) for saving RAM? What's better for my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid reading and storing all input bytes in memory you can use [`InputStream.transerTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) method:

```
try (var in = CreateYourInputStreamHere;
     var out = CreateYourOutputStreamHere) {
  in.transferTo(out);
}
```

In Java 17 this approach will use a 8K buffer, reading and writing a single 8K chunk of data before processing next chunk.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i mean saving clean memory. For example: if i will excract file more than 2gb from zip and have 512mb ram on PC. I correctly understand, read(byte[]) more better for this situation than readAllBytes()?
UPD: Maybe, my understanding in bytes is bad

Comment: @Kazbo You seem to be assuming that the transferTo method will do exactly the same thing you did—that is, read the entire stream into memory.  But that is not the case.  The transferTo method will copy a small amount of bytes, over and over, until the entire InputStream has been read.

Comment: @VGR Oh thanks so much :) I will use transferTo